# How to resolve "TypeError: Ext.getCmp(...).setReadOnly is not a function"

Tags: extjs

I'm setting a field to read only in my application, but I'm getting the above error. The field which I am trying to set to read only is a checkbox field.

I've tried in the below manner to set it to read only:

```
Ext.getCmp('virtualFeederLoadPloarity').setReadOnly(true);
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and also mention the version to track your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext.getCmp('componentId') method takes the component Id.

Check this working example

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
        width:400,
        title:'Test CB',
        renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
        height:200,
        items:[{
            xtype:'checkboxfield',
            id:'cbId',
            name : 'checkbox1',
            fieldLabel: 'Test Checkbox',
            checked: true
        }],
        buttons:[
            {
                text:'Readonly',
                handler:function(){
                    Ext.getCmp('cbId').setReadOnly(true);
                }
            },{
                text:'Disable Readonly',
                handler:function(){
                    Ext.getCmp('cbId').setReadOnly(false);
                }
            }]
    })
}
});
```

[Sencha Fiddle Link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2pg7)

Answer (score 0):

Error message `TypeError: Ext.getCmp(…).setReadOnly is not a function` means, that `Ext.getCmp('virtualFeederLoadPloarity')` is not a field as you expect. Execute `Ext.getCmp()` using your field's id. Also, with code, you may try to check the `xtype` with `getXType()` and see the actual type of your object.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            id: 'myTextField1',
            labelWidth: 50,
            width: 500,
            fieldLabel: 'Names'
        });
        Ext.getCmp('myTextField1').setReadOnly(true);
        alert(Ext.getCmp('myTextField1').getXType()); 
    }
});
```